# How do you convert command line arguments to a double array for calculating sums?

Tags: java

So currently I get a "Sum = 0.0" and a Mean equals "NaN", after fighting a lot of messages that warned agains a "possible lossy conversion from double to int". I think the code is finally taking doubles, but still does not do what I would like it to: take values from the command line, place them into an array, sum these and then calculate the mean.

Any ideas where the errors lie?

```
public class StudentMarks{

protected double[] marks;
//create an array filled with double values

public StudentMarks(double[] marks){
    this.marks = new double[0]; //set the default array size    
    }

    public void setMarks(){
    this.marks = marks;
    }

    public void getArray(){
        //one can only  print arrays using loops.. 
        //took me a little to realise that erm. 

        for(int i=0; i<marks.length; i++)
        System.out.println(marks[i]);
    }

    public double calSum(){

    double totals = 0.0;

    for(double i: marks) {
        //double mLength = Double.parseDouble(marks[i]);
        totals+= i;     
    }
        return totals;
    }

    //A method to calculate the mean of all elements

    public double calMean(){
        double means = (calSum()/marks.length);
        return means;
    }

    //A main method to test

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check to see if the user has actually sent a paramter to the method
        if (args.length != 7){
            System.out.println("Usage: java RandomArray <NUM>. Example: java RandomArray 5");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        double[] prompt = new double[args.length];
        for (int i =0; i<args.length; i++){
            prompt[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
        }
        StudentMarks test = new StudentMarks(prompt);


        test.getArray();

        // Calculate the sum of all the values in the array and print it
        System.out.println("Sum: "+ test.calSum());

        // Calculate the mean of all the values in the array and print it
        System.out.println("Mean: "+ test.calMean());
    }

}
```

Comment: `double[] prompt = new double[args.length];` will always have the length 1 since you check `if (args.length != 1) {...}` right before.

Comment: Please define your input format. You say the input is an array of doubles, yet you only allow there to be one command line argument. Please clarify.

Comment: I made a minor edit allowing for more numbers to be input from the command line, so the delimitation is not 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.marks = new double[0];
```

use

```
this.marks = marks;
```

You are currently assigning the `marks` member variable to be a zero-length array rather than the parameter, so the sum of the elements is zero, and `marks.length` is zero, so `calSum()/marks.length` is `0.0 / 0.0`, which is defined to be `NaN`.

Comment: Or remove the parameter `double[] marks` from the constructor (if you want to keep the standard initialization) and change the `setMarks()` to `setMarks(double[] marks)` (that's how setter methods should work anyway) and use it in your `main()` method.

Comment: @Mel no worries - please consider accepting the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

One problem was in the initializer of the class. The class is currently initialized to a 0 length array. Instead you should initialize it with your input.

Use

```
public StudentMarks(double[] marks){
    this.marks = marks;   
}
```

Instead of

```
public StudentMarks(double[] marks){
    this.marks = new double[0];    
}
```

Here is a fixed up version of the code. Take a look at the inline comments for clarity.

```
public class StudentMarks{

protected double[] marks;
//create an array filled with double values

//Pass in the array of marks to initialize the class
public StudentMarks(double[] marks){
    this.marks = marks; //set the marks array in the class to the passed in one   
}

//Set the class marks variable to the passed in one
public void setMarks(double[] marks){
    this.marks = marks;
}

//Change the name to "printMarks" to better reflect the purpose of the method
public void printMarks(){
    //one can only  print arrays using loops.. 
    //took me a little to realise that erm. 

    for(int i=0; i<marks.length; i++){
        System.out.println(marks[i]);
    }
}

//
public double calSum(){

    double totals = 0.0;

    for(double i: marks) {
        //double mLength = Double.parseDouble(marks[i]);
        totals+= i;     
    }

    return totals;
}

//A method to calculate the mean of all elements
public double calMean(){
    double means = (calSum()/marks.length);
    return means;
}

//A main method to test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Print out an error and exit only if we have less than 1 element passed in
    if (args.length != 7){
        System.out.println("Usage: java RandomArray <NUM>. Example: java RandomArray 5");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    double[] prompt = new double[args.length];
    //Note that there is no error checking here
    for (int i =0; i<args.length; i++){
        prompt[i] = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
    }

    //Initialize the StudentMarks class with the value of the input
    StudentMarks test = new StudentMarks(prompt);

    test.printMarks();

    // Calculate the sum of all the values in the array and print it
    System.out.println("Sum: "+ test.calSum());

    // Calculate the mean of all the values in the array and print it
    System.out.println("Mean: "+ test.calMean());
}

}
```

Comment: "The application would break any time more than one argument is passed in." At the time you posted this, OP had updated the condition to `!= 7`; OP appears to have a very specific requirement on that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Andy Turner. At the time I wrote the code, the OP still has `!=1`, so I made an assumption, and changed it. You are correct though, it looks like they have a specific requirement. I've edited my code to match that.

Comment: "There were actually a couple of issues with the code above." Is this now true that you removed the thing about `length < 1`? I would tend to avoid posting large dumps of code because it's not very clear what (and why) you changed semantically other than that constructor (you have to scroll up and down the page to see the changes, not very easy). Don't forget that things that are clearer to you aren't necessarily clearer to others reading it.

Comment: Edited again to reflect the changes in OP. My choice to post the complete code was driven by 2 factors. First, it looks like the OP is by a new engineer and I wasn't sure if pointing to one line would help them. This way they have a working piece of code to compare against. My second reason, that there was more than one problem in the code, is now mute. I do appreciate the criticism though, and will keep this in mind in the future.